# How do you hide your php source code?

Tags: php, hide

I have a php page which contains keys and salts and I would like to hide such information just in case. Anyone know a good free software that could do this?

I have both zend and ion installed on my server, which I heard some source scramblers use. Any ideas?

Comment: From whom do you try to hide it?

Comment: You do know that anyone viewing your PHP files via the browser wont be able to read your code, right?

Comment: how about this ? http://www.sourceguardian.com/

Comment: I meant in case my server gets hacked. Since the php file contains my keys, salts, and encrypt/decrypt functions. I'm going to tie the php file to my domain too. Looking for a free solution. Hope that clears my question a bit. Help is appreciated!

Comment: sourceguardian looks good, but it's not free :(

Comment: how about this one ? http://www.rssoftlab.com/phpenc.php

Comment: You can see any solution on a different link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185455/can-i-hide-php-extension-in-html-source-code/53299741#53299741

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your PHP source cannot be viewed directly via browser. You can obfuscate the php files on the server for extra protection. Obfuscation makes it **more difficult** for an attacker to understand your code, **if** he eventually gets in. Remember to keep an un-obfuscated back-up of your files.

Check Out

[Obf](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/PHPObfuscator.jsp)

http://www.pipsomania.com/best_php_obfuscator.do

[Zend Guard](http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://zend.com/products/zend_guard&ei=TsF_Tp3TA8S3hAem2Lkv&usg=AFQjCNF-A56A3tOMqSBwRHik-2mz5khLzw)

Or just search for http://www.google.com.ng/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+obfuscator

Comment: @Jan Of-course. Everything that can be encrypted, obfuscated, can be reversed.